# Using Einstein STO outside of Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, einstein, email-studio

I know Einstein STO is designed to use within Journey Builder, but I also know I can use it to send ad hoc emails via an Automation Studio Send Email event.

My question is, once I create that event, can I deploy the email via Email Studio's User Initiated Send or do I need to create an automation just for that event? If I go the Email Studio route, will the STO still be enabled? I assume so but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @EasyE but I can send that activity two ways - user initiated send or automation - will both work for STO?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are either an automation studio activity or a journey